# Assertions for CLI Commands in CI/CD environment

Tags: cypress

I am working with a Cypress testing framework in a CI/CD environment. There are several Cypress smoke tests that run each time my team pushes a build. However, I would like to add tests that make assertions based on command line responses. Specifically, I want to ensure that there are no merge conflicts in the code base by creating a test that checks that "git grep --ignore-case "<<<< HEAD" results in 'not found'.

What options do I have to implement such a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to roll your own bash script you can model it on mine at

https://durrantm.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/tdd-for-sh/
See below.

So you could do something like:

```
# Define the function
$ check_git () { git grep '>>>>> HEAD' && return 1; return 0; }

# Call the function
$ check_git
# do something based on return code - $?
# "To check the exit code we can simply print the $? special variable in bash.
# This variable will print the exit code of the last run command"
```

The code below is the full detail of my code which essentially lets you use

```
do_test some_bash_function expected_result other_param1 other_param2 ...
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
. colors_for_text.sh 2> /dev/null

do_test () {
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    printf "$fail_color Error - do_test: No parameters provided - Usage is do_test [function_name] \$LINENO [expected result] [optional params]\n"
    exit 1
  elif [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
    printf "$fail_color Error - do_test: Two parameters missing - \$LINENO and expected result (other params as needed)\n"
    exit 1
  fi
  declare -ig test_runs test_passes test_fails
  local -r function="$1";shift
  local -r line_number="$1";shift
  local failfast="False"
  local debug="False"
  local verbose="False"
  local test_description=
  local test_matcher=
  local expected=
  local pass_on_params=
  local command_not_found=False
  type "setup" &> /dev/null && setup
  # TODO Replace with for loop (initial attempts failed)
  [[ "$1" == "failfast" ]] && failfast="True" && shift
  [[ "$1" == "debug" ]] && debug="True" && shift
  [[ "$1" == "verbose" ]] && verbose="True" && shift
  [[ "$1" == "failfast" ]] && failfast="True" && shift
  [[ "$1" == "debug" ]] && debug="True" && shift
  [[ "$1" == "failfast" ]] && failfast="True" && shift
  if [[ "$1" =~ ^description= ]]; then
    [[ `echo $1 | grep =` ]] && test_description=`echo $1 | sed 's/.*=//'`' ' &&
    shift
  fi
  if [[ "$1" =~ ^matcher= ]]; then
    [[ `echo "$1" | grep =` ]] && test_matcher="`echo "$1" | sed 's/matcher=//'`" &&
    shift
  fi
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    printf "$fail_color Error - Function: $function, Line: $line_number \n
do_test: Third parameter missing - expected result\n"
    exit 1
  fi
  expected="$1";shift
  pass_on_params="$@"
  $function ${pass_on_params[@]} 2> $TMPDIR"/output$$-"$test_runs".txt"
  cat $TMPDIR"/output$$-"$test_runs".txt" | grep -i "command not found" &&
    command_not_found=True
  debug_printf "(debug)"
  if [[ $command_not_found == "True" ]]; then
    record_script_failure "$function"
  elif [[ "$test_matcher" == "==" ]]; then
    [[ "$result" == $expected ]] &&
    record_test_success "$function" ||
    record_test_failure "$function";
  elif [[ "$expected" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    [[ "$result" -eq $expected ]] &&
    record_test_success "$function" ||
    record_test_failure "$function";
  else
    [[ "$result" == $expected ]] &&
    record_test_success "$function" ||
    record_test_failure "$function";
  fi
  test_runs+=1
}
record_test_success () {
  [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && no_param_quit $FUNCNAME
  local -r function="$1"
  printf "$pass_color"."$color_end"
  [[ "$verbose" == "True" ]] && printf "$function"
  test_passes+=1
}
record_test_failure () {
  [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && no_param_quit $FUNCNAME
  local -r function="$1"
  test_fails+=1
  printf "$fail_color"F"$color_end"
  function_exists? "$function" &&
    error_messages=$error_messages"$fail_color""$test_description""Line: $line_number - \
'$function ${pass_on_params[@]}' failed:\n\
Expected: $expected\n\
Received: $result $color_end\n\n" ||
    error_messages=$error_messages"$fail_color""Line: $line_number: \
Function '$function' is undefined\n"
  [[ "$failfast" == "True" ]] && failfast "Test" $error_messages
}
record_script_failure () {
  [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && no_param_quit $FUNCNAME
  local -r function="$1"
  test_fails+=1
  err=`cat $TMPDIR"/output$$-"$test_runs".txt"`
  printf $err
  error_messages=$error_messages"$fail_color""Line: $line_number: \
Error within function '$function', getting \"command not found\" in $err \n"
  [[ "$failfast" == "True" ]] && failfast "Script" $error_messages
}
failfast () {
  printf "\n$1 error & failfast set to exit immediately.\n$2\n" && exit 1
}

no_param_quit () {
  printf "\nError - 1 parameter required for: $1 - exiting\n" && exit 1
}
function_exists?() {
    declare -f -F $1 > /dev/null
    return $?
}
debug_echo () {
  [[ "$debug" == "True" ]] && echo "$1"
}
debug_printf () {
  [[ "$debug" == "True" ]] && printf "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Assert.sh](https://github.com/lehmannro/assert.sh) or [bash-assert](https://github.com/orangemug/bash-assert/) if you want to write Bash or subprocess if you want to run using a Python script:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.call(["ping", "-c 2", "www.cyberciti.biz"])
```

Then you can simply assert on the `output`.